# Is it possible to automatically pass a methods value as a parameter in another method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

Context: I am writing code that requires me to check if strings pass certain tests. These tests are easier to code when the strings they work with have no spaces in them. So what I have done is write a helper method to remove the spaces, then at the start of each test (which takes in a string as input), I create a new variable that contains the result of the helper method called with the string input to the test method, and then I use the new variable for all the testing.

What I want to do is make it so that I do not have to add that new variable in each line, and instead, whenever the test is called with some string, it will automatically use the value returned by the helper method with that same string as input.

Code example:

```py
def spaceStrip(self, txt):
    #returns the string with no spaces

def testFunc(self, txt):
    newText = self.spaceStrip(txt)
    *test code with newText*
```

I don't know if this is possible or even plausible, and it certainly isn't required to make the code work. I just want to get a somewhat deeper understanding of the language.

Comment: Look up the concept of a `decorator`.  Yes, a function can be an argument to another function.

Answer (score 1):

you could write your `spaceStrip` function as a decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps

def spaceStrip(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(txt):
       newText = self.spaceStrip(txt)
       return fn(newText)

    return wrapper


@spaceStrip
def testFunc(txt):
    # test code with txt (it is stripped)
    pass
```